# "Скільки копійок?" та "Яка кількість копійок?"

Tags: вживання-слів

Є дві монети номіналами 5 та 10 копійок.

Відповідь на питання «*Скільки монет?*» — «*Дві*».
На питання «*Скільки копійок?*» більшість відповість — «*П'ятнадцять*».
На питання «*Яка кількість копійок?*» можна відповісти як «*Дві*», так і «*П'ятнадцять*».

Згідно [Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C):

> Кількість відповідає на запитання «Скільки (цього є там)?»

Чи є різниця між запитаннями «Скільки?» та «Яка кількість?», та як правильно відповідати на них?

Comment: Незрозуміло, чому на питання "Яка кількість копійок?" можна відповісті "дві" в даному випадку.

Comment: Так, таке враження що "Яка кількість" перетворює копійки в монети :)

Comment: До обох попередніх коментарів: той, хто вивчає мову, може плутати ці поняття. Якби ви знали, скільки жартів-каламбурів існує у китайській стосовно слова 多少, і скільки помилок роблять учні… Тож не варто дивуватися таким запитанням.

Answer (score 4):

**[Копійка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0)** — грошова одиниця (1 грн = 100 коп).

**[Монета](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)** — грошовий знак, виготовлений з металу. Це одна з [форм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9) грошей. Інший приклад форми — [купюра](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B0).

> Скільки грошей?

**25 копійок.** Незалежно, це одна монета 25 номіналом копійок чи 25 монет по одній копійці.

> Скільки монет?

**20 монет** — незалежно від номіналу кожної.